# Can't install textract on Ubuntu because of Pillow

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install textract on Ubuntu Digital Ocean VPS (python 2.7.6) using `pip` (tried `easy_install too`).

The problem is that it returns almost the same error like in Windows.

I checked http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html which didn't say anything about this error. For my version of Python, it should work.

**pip install textract**

```
root@solutions-for-languages-beta:/home/django/SolutionsForLanguages# pip install textract
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): textract in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argcomplete in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): chardet in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-pptx>=0.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docx2txt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): xlrd in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): EbookLib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): SpeechRecognition>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from textract)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-pptx>=0.5.1->textract)
Downloading/unpacking Pillow>=2.6.1 (from python-pptx>=0.5.1->textract)
  Downloading Pillow-4.0.0.tar.gz (11.1MB): 11.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-pptx>=0.5.1->textract)
Downloading/unpacking olefile (from Pillow>=2.6.1->python-pptx>=0.5.1->textract)
  Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB): 74kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/olefile/setup.py) egg_info for package olefile

Installing collected packages: Pillow, olefile
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution


    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ECs4iy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching '*.sh'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'

warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext





The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>

    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)

__main__.RequiredDependencyException:



The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html





----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ECs4iy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

**pip install Pillow**

```
root@solutions-for-languages-beta:/home/django/SolutionsForLanguages# pip install Pillow
Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-4.0.0.tar.gz (11.1MB): 11.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking olefile (from Pillow)
  Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB): 74kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/olefile/setup.py) egg_info for package olefile

Installing collected packages: Pillow, olefile
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution


    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3CmTo2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching '*.sh'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'

warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'

warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext





The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py", line 791, in <module>

    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)

__main__.RequiredDependencyException:



The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,

a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.



Please see the install instructions at:

   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html





----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3CmTo2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: What about in a virtualenv? Does it work then?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Just tried it and yes, on virtualenv it works.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-pillow` or `python-pil` or whatever...

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik It could well be that it's clashing with something installed on the server then. If I was deploying a web app to a server I would always put it in a virtualenv because there's too much risk of it clashing with a package installed by the system otherwise. Not sure if that's an option for you, but it's usually considered the best approach. Either that or install the official package using apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you need install:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Later you can have problem with freetype, assume package:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

can help.

For CentOs (6.5):

```
sudo yum install -y libjpeg-devel freetype-devel
```